# How to find all nodetypes containing a particular field?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6, cck

How do I find all nodetypes containing a particular field?

Suppose for example I have two nodetypes, "mybio" and "myresume", and both nodetypes contain a field "myphoto".  Is there a function that takes the name of my field as input ("myphoto") and returns the names of the nodetypes containing this field ("mybio" and "myresume")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a function but looking at the database structure for CCK something like this would do the trick:

```
function content_field_get_node_types($field_name) {
  $query = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT type_name FROM {content_node_field_instance} WHERE field_name = '%s'", $field_name);

  $node_types = array();
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($query)) {
    $node_types[] = $row['type_name'];
  }

  return $node_types;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CCK provides an administration page where you can see the association between content types and fields: Administer > Content types > Fields (path: `www.example.com/admin/content/types/fields`)

And if you look at the source code, you'll see that in this function `content_fields_list()` (`sites\all\modules\cck\includes\content.admin.inc`) is where the magic happens.

You can view the SQL in the source here: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--includes--content.admin.inc/function/content_fields_list/6